# What is the difference between commands "wc `grep -l int *`" and "grep -l int * | wc"?

Tags: unix, grep, command, wc

What is the difference between these two commands:

```
wc `grep -l int *`
grep -l int * | wc
```

How does the output differ?

Comment: Have you tried the commands?  Do a `man wc`.  `wc` gives number of lines, number of words, number of letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wc `grep -l int *`
```

This will give you count of words/lines/characters for each file containing string "int".

```
grep -l int * | wc`
```

This will give you count of words/lines/characters of the output generated by `grep -l int *`